# Run a PY script on client machine but use import packages from remote server

Tags: python, pyinstaller, remote-access, remote-server, face-recognition

What i am trying to do is the following, I have a server and several clients.

I would like my py script to use and access the already installed/imported packages on the remote server.

Currently i have a server code set up (below) but i was not able to find anything on google regarding using the packages already installed on another machine.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
print('Socket created')
port = 56789
s.bind(('',port))
print(f'socket binded to port {port}')
s.listen(5)
print('socket is listening')
while True:
c, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected from', addr)
    message = ('you are connected')
    c.send(message.encode())
    c.close()
```

Client:

```py
import socket
s = socket.socket()
port = 56789
s.connect(('ip',port))
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

Unfotunately i am unable to package the whole pyscript because mediapipe (error below) using PyInstaller
[image]

Python version 3.8.4

Comment: This is not possible, but even if it was, it would be a chicken-and-egg problem. How are you planning to start the client software, with all those missing packages, before it can connect to the remote server?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! the client script is "scheduled" to start at logon and wait for vpn connection. What i am trying to avoid is having to install python and all the packages on each and every machine to run the said script as i would like it to be as plug and play as possible. I tried to package the script in an EXE file but from my understanding the mediapipe files are loaded dynamically ... ( PyInstaller )

Comment: I'm not talking about that. The client won't start and connect to the remote server, because it can't import the required packages.

Comment: yeah,i understand that, thank you for the answer! but any light on what i am trying to do with packaging it up?

Comment: @hectic Try if this will help you with creating .exe file for your client package: https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2162